# Cannot delete CloudObject in CloudBoost

Tags: object, cloudboost

I've got this object:

```
CB.CloudObject {document: Object, $$hashKey: "object:23"}
    document: Object
        ACL: CB.ACL
        _id: "tBaA9LXZ"
        _tableName: "Product"
        _type: "custom"
        _version: 2
        category: Object
        title: "Nombre"
        user: CB.CloudUser
```

When I try to delete it, it gives me this error:

> TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Is this due to user Relation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved!

A part from CloudUser relation (which is not the problem) I was setting a column named category that was a CloudObject, but I was not setting it as Relation, I was seeting it as object.

Changing it by a Relation solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's due to circular relations. Do you have something like A -> B and B -> A. In this case, Can you remove relational objects and try again.

Comment: mmm, I don't think so. CloudObject contains CloudUser but CloudUser does not contain CloudObject. Also, I cannot delete CloudUser, I only want to delete the CloudObject and its relation.

Maybe I have to unset user relation before delete the CloudObject?

Comment: Can you help me with sample code, so I can replicate.

Comment: I am only doing a obj.delete(), where obj is a CloudObject and has a column named 'user' which is a relation to CloudUser. The error callback is not fired, the exception is thrown before.

For example, I have tried to delete a user and there is no problem (user is a CloudUser object that don't have any relation)

Comment: The error is fired inside CB.CloudObject.prototype.delete method in line **var params=JSON.stringify({
        key: CB.appKey,
        document: CB.toJSON(thisObj)
    });**